# Question about setting up Cognito to login to S3 website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Have a simple 1 page s3 website, my goal is to force users to go through Cognito to get there.

Couple questions:

1. Does the callback URL simply tell cognito where to go after login? Is there any kind of authentication here? Would the user be able to go straight to my website if they knew the S3 endpoint?
2. If that first option doesn't work, which I don't think it does, can I use this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html?
3. Or do I have to make cognito generate a JWT token and write the needed javascript (is amplify mandatory?) to make it work? If I go this route is cloudfront->api gateway, and the gateway handles the token a better option?

Have never done login type stuff before so not sure if there are multiple routes or I am even thinking about this correctly.

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

1. Callback URL is the address cognito sends its tokens to. You can use
   javascript to read these tokens to exchange them for temporary AWS
   credentials. So this URL will need to have a script which will
   consume these tokens, get temporary credentials, and then use these
   credentials to request aws resource access.
2. The first method is not optional. You have to get the tokens and
   exchange them for AWS credentials.
3. Amplify is not mandatory, it will just make your life a lot easier.
   Tokens expire in an hour and need to be refreshed. Amplify handles
   all of this for you.

Additionally, cognito offers something called as hosted GUI, which will create a login page for you and let you define redirect/callback URL.